# Flask->Is there any other way of using the login_user of flask_login without comitting to a database?

Tags: python, flask

I've noticed that whenever I use login_user it gives me 401-Unauthorized if before this I haven't added the said User to the database. Is there a way to use login_user without adding the user to the database and without the 401-Unauthorized ??
Here's my function where it all happens

```
@app.route('/Index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Index():
    if request.method=='POST':
        New_Username = request.form['Username']
        New_Password = request.form['Password']
        user = bool(Users.query.filter_by(Username=New_Username).first())
        if user is not None and user == False:
            New_User = Users(Username=New_Username, Password=New_Password)
            db.session.add(New_User)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(New_User)
            print('Works')
            return redirect('/Dashboard')
        else:
            New_User = Users(Username=New_Username, Password=New_Password)
            login_user(New_User)
            print('Doesnt work')
            return redirect('/Dashboard')
    else:
        return render_template('Index.html', New_User=All_Users)
```

Comment: um, are you storing plaintext passwords in your database

Comment: I am, although I'll change it later on. It's all experimental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `login_user` needs a User class entity.

Your use of capital letters is unconventional and may cause obscure problems.  For one, does your `Users` class have uppercase params?  Usually, `username` and `password` are lowercase.

And, no need for the `bool`.

Here is more conventional casing, standard `User` model, etc.:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method=='POST':
        new_username = request.form['username']
        new_password = request.form['password']
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=new_username).first()
        if not user:
            new_user = User(username=new_username, password=new_password)
            new_user.save()
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(new_user)
            print('Works')
            return redirect('/dashboard')
        else:
            login_user(user)
            print('Doesnt work')
            return redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        # All_Users not defined!
        return render_template('index.html', new_user=All_Users)
```

Comment: The users class does have uppercase params